# Improving the use of selectizeInput in the context of select a ticker from a long list of tickers

Tags: r, shiny

I have a long list of 500 tickers (the code associated with the price for common stock of a listed company) or more, and I want the user to be able to find and select 1 without selecting an invalid ticker and returning an error -- may retain the current value until the user replaces with a new and correct value.

This is minimal example

```
tickers <- c(
  "IBM1", "GLW1", "RBLX1", "SNOW1", "F1", "GM1", "AAPL1", "A1", "IBM2", "GLW2", "RBLX2", "SNOW2", "F2", "GM2", "AAPL2", "A2",
  "IBM3", "GLW3", "RBLX3", "SNOW3", "F3", "GM3", "AAPL3", "A3"
)
tickers <- tickers[order(tickers)]



# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "ticker",
        label = "Search",
        choices = tickers,
        selected = "NVDA",
        multiple = FALSE, # allow for multiple inputs
        options = list(create = FALSE) # if TRUE, allows newly created inputs
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
    )
  )
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  firmNum <- reactive({
    if (length(which(tickers == input$ticker)) > 0) {
      paste(which(tickers == input$ticker))
    } else {
      "ERROR!!!!!!!"
    }
  })
  output$value <- renderPrint({
    firmNum()
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and it works, but say the user types in GM rather than waiting for the user to select from GM1, GM2 or GM3 it returns an error.  Is there an easy fix to this?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Is the problem that "ERROR!!!!!!!" is displayed when "GM" is typed into the `selectizeInput`?

Comment: Yes, as soon as you type you get an error, would rather it wait for a return or something.   I figured it out, let me "answer my own question" .  Thanks for thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Since someone asked about the question and I had already figured it out, I think it makes sense to answer my own question.
I got it to work the why I want it to by creating a function updateTicker, that will always provide two valid tickers. If a new ticker that is valid has been provided it will provide that one.  If not, it will provide the prior one. This ensurest that one does not see "ERROR!!!!" when mistyping a ticker.  Here is the minimal example.

```
tickers <- c(
  "IBM1", "GLW1", "RBLX1", "SNOW1", "F1", "GM1", "AAPL1", "A1", "IBM2", "GLW2", "RBLX2", "SNOW2", "F2", "GM2", "AAPL2", "A2",
  "IBM3", "GLW3", "RBLX3", "SNOW3", "F3", "GM3", "AAPL3", "A3"
)
tickers <- tickers[order(tickers)]

# this function takes as an inputs a vector of strings
# if there is only one element and it is in the vector tickers it will return them twice
# if it is not in the vector tickers it will return the first element of the vector tickers
# it two elements are provided it will return them both if they are both valid
# if the first element is not value it will return the second element twice

updateTicker = function(strings) {

  if (length(which(tickers == strings[1])) > 0)
  {strings[1] = strings[1]} else
  {strings[1] = strings[2]}
  if (length(strings) == 1) {strings = c(strings,strings)  }
  if (sum(is.na(strings)) == 2)  {strings = tickers[c(1,1)]}
  if (is.na(strings)[[1]] == T)  {strings = rep(strings[2],2)}
  return(strings)
}


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(
        inputId = "ticker",
        label = "Search",
        choices = tickers,
        selected = "NVDA",
        multiple = FALSE, # allow for multiple inputs
        options = list(create = FALSE) # if TRUE, allows newly created inputs
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
    )
  )
)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram


server <- function(input, output) {

  newTicker = reactive({updateTicker(input$ticker)})
  firmNum = reactive({ which(tickers==newTicker()[[1]]) })

  output$value <- renderPrint({
    firmNum()
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```